# The critical values of a map from a Torus to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f(x,y,z)=z$ be the height function on a Torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Computing the representation of the differential of $f$ with respect to these coordinates, we get $f_{*,p}=\left(\begin{array}{c c c}0& 0& 1\end{array}\right)$, which has rank $1$ (and this rank is coordinate independent). Therefore, every point in the Torus should be a regular point. However, Loring Tu's book states that there are 4 critical points... Where did I go wrong?

Addendum for future reference:
In page 91, the proposition 8.11 is written with respect to the charts of the Torus. The Torus is of dimension 2, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) link, so our charts with domain the Torus are not $x,y,z$ but $\phi(x,y,z)=(\theta,\varphi)$, such that $\theta,\varphi$ parametrize the Torus as in the wikipedia link. (We must switch the z with x in the wiki's parametrization to get the vertical Torus in Tu's book, i.e. $z=(R+r\cos(\theta))\cos(\varphi)$ ). We must think with respect to the parametrization to apply proposition 8.11.

Comment: Could you give me the page of the book?

Comment: @positrón0802 page 97

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the torus. Your matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is the differential of the map $\pi:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto z$ (which is linear hence equals its own differential). Your function $f:\mathbb{T}\to \mathbb{R}$ is the composition of the inclusion $\iota:\mathbb{T}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\pi.$ Hence $df_p=\pi\circ d\iota_p:T_p\mathbb{T}\to \mathbb{R}.$ So $df_p$ fail to be surjective when $d\iota_p(T_p\mathbb{R})$ is contained in the kernel of $\pi,$ which is the span of $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0),$ i.e. the $xy$ plane. So $p$ is critical when its tangent plane is horizontal.

Comment: positrón, many thanks for your answer. To accept your answer, could you just tell me how one would obtain $d\iota_p$? I don't understand how one defines $\iota$ on a Torus...

Comment: I'm considering the torus $\mathbb{T}$ as the "doughnut" surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as drawn in page 97 in Tu's book, so $\iota:\mathbb{T}\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is just the inclusion and $d\iota_p:T_p\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ would be the inclusion of the tangent plane of the torus at $p$ into $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Comment: Positrón, I still have some doubts. I'm sorry if they are somewhat 'dumb' on my part, but I'm self-studying this. My two questions are:  

1) How is it different to consider just $\mathbb{T}$ from $\mathbb{T} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$?

2) I've tried drawing the tangent plane, and for the 2 points in the 'outer circle' I get the tangent plane is only in the xy plane. However, why is the tangent plane for the 2 points in the 'inner circle' also in the xy plane?

I would really appreciate your help, Positrón.

Comment: Don't worry at all. 1) $\mathbb{T}$ here is defined as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (a surface), sometimes when considering a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is convenient to "forget" about the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^n$ in which it lies, but not in this problem. 2) Take the draw and try to see how the tangent plane changes while one moves around the 'inner circle' from say 'left' to 'right', it starts being vertical and then the "slope" is being reduced to the point of being horizontal and then the "slope" increases again to the point of being vertical again in the 'right' side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the restriction of the differential at the tangent point of $x\in T^2$, $T_xT^2$ is a 2-dimensional subspace which may be horizontal and for such a point $x$  $df_x$ is critical.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm not getting it. Could you please elaborate a bit more. The tangent space at those points will be 2-dim. So you're saying that in every point of Torus, the basis of the tangent space is just $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\}$? Also, how do we reconcile that with the condition that all the partial derivatives must be equal to zero?

Comment: yes, this is true, the best way to see this draw a picture or see a picture of a torus of lines you will see that, you can also compute the equation of the tangent space.